# pass URL parameter in developer mode (latest code)

Tags: google-apps-script

how do i pass a URL parameter in a web-app developer mode? (run latest code from within the GAS editor)

this does not work:
`https://script.google.com/a/macros/gappspro.com/s/web-app-key&myparam=xyz/dev`
does not work, page unknown.

passing param in URL seems to work only in "runtime" as seen below.
this does work:
`https://script.google.com/a/macros/gappspro.com/exec?service=web-app-key&myparam=xyz`

Answer (score 3):

Get the url from the IDE (ends in "dev") and then put the params after the "/dev". For example ....."/dev?myparam=one&another=two"